# How to implement a walkthrough screen like a dialog fragment in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create a screen like this. I want to create a walkthrough screen, which will contain more than 4 screens. There will be a next button at the bottom right corner. And I want to display it like a popup dialog.

[Raw Sketch of desired UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x9rH.jpg)

Please can anyone help me with this?

Comment: and what did you try until now?

Comment: I tried using view pager and navigation component, but this approach does not satisfy the need to display screen in popup style. (Just like a DialogFragment). 
I also tried implementing custom dialog class, but the app crashes everytime I try to show the cust dialog .